# Is WordPress Theme Customization with child theme cause any risk on future update

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a newcomer to Avada theme customization. I want to create a new header for my theme. Now I create a new child theme, then create a new header.php and want to add my code on this.

So, is it a good idea to customize in this way? Or is there any risk on a future update, if I develop my theme with a child theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, is it a good idea to customize in this way?

Yes, it is a good idea and recommended to create a child theme instead of modifying the parent theme. This is to keep your modifications in case an update is released.

For more info about creating child themes and other useful info, you can visit [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Creating_a_Child_Theme_from_an_Unmodified_Parent_Theme).